# how can I pass parameter from Activity to function in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I want to pass my parameter from activity to fragment how can I do it?

**Activity.java**

```
fragment.getViewProfileMainActivity(SendViewProfileName, SendViewProfileEmail, SendViewProfilePhone, SendViewProfileCity, SendViewProfileGender, SendViewProfileBirthdate, SendViewProfilePhotoUrl);
```

**Fragment.java**

```
getViewProfileMainActivity(String Profile, ...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing messages between various components of your app, I would highly recommend you to use the seasoned solution of publisher/subscriber using [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)

- To add EventBus as a dependency in your project, add the following line in your app-level build.gralde file:

```java
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

Note that at the time of writing this answer, the latest version was 3.1.1. You should check the latest version from [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.greenrobot%20AND%20a:eventbus) and include that.

- Define your event class as a simple POJO:

```java
    public class MessageEvent {
        public final String message;

        public MessageEvent(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
```

- In your Fragment, add this code to listen to the event

```java
    // This method will be called when a MessageEvent is posted (in the UI thread for Toast)
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // do something here
    }
```

- In your Fragment, add this code to register to and unregister from the bus:

```java
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }
```

- Finally, from your Activity, post events:

```java
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("Hello everyone!"));
```

Your Fragment will receive this message.

---

Coming to your particular example, you can do so as follows:

- Your event POJO class should be:

```java
    public class MessageEvent {
        public final String SendViewProfileName;
        public final String SendViewProfileEmail;
        // similarly other params

        public MessageEvent(String SendViewProfileName, String SendViewProfileEmail, ...) {
            this.SendViewProfileName = SendViewProfileName;
            this.SendViewProfileEmail = SendViewProfileEmail;
            // similarly other params
        }
    }
```

- When the event occurs, you can execute your desired method in your Fragment as:

```java
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
        getViewProfileMainActivity(event.SendViewProfileName, ...);
    }

    private getViewProfileMainActivity(Profile, ...) {
         // your function definition here
    }
```

- From your Activity, you can post the event as:

```java
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent(SendViewProfileName, SendViewProfileEmail, ...));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow it's works, Thankyou!, is that library has something like bad effect, like API below 21 will become crash?

Comment: You're welcome! I've been using this library for 4+ years in various production level apps with 10 million+ downloads, and have not faced any problems at all.

Comment: What a relief, because I need to publish this app to any type of OS, thankyou this library help me too from crashing when switching between fragment

Answer (score 1):

Covered in the training at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver

You just need get the fragment in your Activity

```java
ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);
```

and then handle if it does not exist yet

Comment: it's works, but when I switching between fragment it will crash, Process: com.indofun.android.indojoy, PID: 813
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.indofun.android.indojoy.Support.HomePageFragment cannot be cast to com.indofun.android.indojoy.Support.ProfilePageFragment
        at com.indofun.android.indojoy.MainActivity.SetViewProfile(MainActivity.java:1579)
        at com.indofun.android.indojoy.MainActivity$18$1.run(MainActivity.java:1423)